# Text inside circles in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I know there are many questions asked related to this. However, still, I couldn't figure out how to do that. I want to generate an image like the following.[image: Text inside circles in Tikz]

The following is what I tried.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}
\node[venn circle, minimum size=8cm, draw, fill=purple] (a) {abc};
\node[venn circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, fill=green] at (0:0.9cm) (b) {def};
\node[venn circle, minimum size=4cm, draw, fill=blue] at (0:1.9cm) (c) {hij};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can someone help me to put text as the figure I have attached?

Comment: You can produce this easily with the methods from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69359/194703). You will more likely get explicit answers if you at least punch in the extensive text that is to go in the nodes.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: Thanks a lot :)